# How do I call a method of an object when I have a string with the name of the object?

Tags: javascript

I've got an object that contains methods that I want to call.

```
myOb  = {    
 f1 : function() {
     console.log("hello from f1") ;
  }
}
```

I've got the name of the object in the form of a string.

```
str = "myOb" ;
```

How do I call a method on myOb when I have it's name in the form of a string?

Comment: Put the object inside a map (or object) so that you can loop it up by name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1.Global scope

You have to use `this` statement which is a **reference** to the `window` object.

```
this[str].f1();
```

Example:

```js
myOb  = {    
 f1 : function() {
     console.log("hello from f1") ;
  }
}
str = "myOb" ;
this[str].f1();
```

### 2.Local scope

If you have `local` scope you could use `bind` method.

```js
myOb  = {    
 f1 : function() {
     console.log("hello from f1") ;
  }
}
str = "myOb";
(function() {  
    this[str].f1();    
}).bind(this)();
```

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't know if I would have thought of doing it this way, but it makes sense. All global variables become properties of the global object, which can be accessed in the global scope via `this`. But you are right, this is a really unusual way of doing things, code should be designed in a way that doesn't require this kind of thing. I would recommend the approach Bergi mentioned in his comment on the question, if you know you are going to need to access something by name rather than reference, store it in an object and access it there rather than via the global object.

Comment: @UselessCode mine wasn't a comment on the fact that this is a weird way to do it (but I admit my first thought was what Bergi suggested too), I was just curious as to why/how one knows this, just so I can learn too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to do that (also works with NodeJS).

```js
myOb  = {
 f1 : function() {
     console.log("hello from f1") ;
  }
}

str = "myOb" ;
eval(str).f1()
```